# open header location in new pop up window?

Tags: php, jquery, window, hyperlink

I'm trying to see if i can open a header location like this:

```
if ($_GET['id'] == 99993) {
    header("Location: page.php");
}
```

and get it to open in a jQuery pop up window ('prettyPhoto' an online jQuery pop up window)

my normal a href links would be written like this:

```
<a href="page.php?iframe=true&height=260"   rel="prettyPhoto[1]">Link</a>
```

but i have no idea how to write it for a header location. can someone please show me. thanks.

Comment: That's called a "redirect".  I don't think the server can specify that the returned page should be displayed in a popup (whether it's a redirect or regular HTML is irrelevant). It has to be specified in the HTML that opens the page, normally using the `target` attribute.

Comment: doesn't make sense that `href` is same `url` as redirect. WHy won't plugin just load correct file?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to the pretty photo URL instead of the php file.

header("Location: http://yoursite.com/page?pretty_photo_url");