# opening header redirect in a new pop up window?

Tags: php, redirect, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [open header location in new pop up window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016395/open-header-location-in-new-pop-up-window)

can someone please let me know of a possible way i can set a header redirect in php to open in a new window.

I have a jquery pop up window i am using called pretty photo.
normally when a user clicks a link the page will open in that (heres the code:)

```
<a href="link.php?iframe=true&height=260"   rel="prettyPhoto[1]">Link</a>
```

So now im trying to get the header redirect to open 'limit.php' to open in the same pretty photo pop up window.

this is what i mean, heres my code for header redirect:

```
header('Location: limit.php');
```

If i can't get the header redirect to do this can i not simply put a code in the limit.php file to say if opened - open using pretty photo?

Comment: what is `link.php`?? can't you change `link.php` to `limit.php`? and where you have wrote `header(...)`??

Comment: link.php is just an example but yes its suppose to be limit.php, header is already redirecting to limit.php but i want limit.php to open in a new pop up window.

Comment: then replace `link.php` with `limit.php`. You don't need that header thing to open `limit.php`. And let me know what happens/

Comment: Here is the demo of what you want. [**LINK**](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#iframe-overview)

Comment: **DO NOT** repost unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using javascript.

```
<a href="http://limit.php" onClick="javascript:void window.open('http://limit.php',width=700,height=500, resizable=1, left=0, top=0'); return false;">Show Pop-up</a>
```

Comment: you mean put this in limit.php the file i want opened in the new pop up window after header has redirected to it from the parent window?

Comment: in link.php do this `include('limit.php')`